# Font that supports all utf-8 characters for php imagettftext

Tags: php, utf-8, truetype, imagettftext

I'm using imagettftext in php to generate images. Is there a true type font that supports all utf-8 characters?

Comment: UTF-8 is an encoding for Unicode code-points (characters). So I'm not sure what your question is. There's something like 100,000+ code-points in Unicode.

Comment: I'm generating images in php using imagettftext. It doesn't show all utf-8 characters in the fonts I've tried. How I can generate images that support any utf-8 character?

Comment: Ok, well again, UTF-8 is just an encoding to represent a Unicode character. I don't know if there is any font that supports every single Unicode code point.

Comment: I ended up using Arial Unicode.ttf which has almost every language you could want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest you can get is Google Noto Fonts.

Sans and Serif support 582 languages while Mono supports 212 languages.

Link and more information here: https://www.google.com/get/noto/

Answer (score 13):

As Brian Neal stated in his comments, UTF-8 is just one of several encoding standards that can represent *every character in the Unicode character set*, which currently contains more than 100000 entries.

So you are actually asking for a true type font that supports all 100k+ unicode characters currently in use on this planet (and it's a moving target, as the set gets expanded and adjusted constantly).

So I guess the literal answer is no, and you should probably check your preconditions (what character subsets are likely encountered in your use case), and search for a fitting multi-purpose font.

However, there are attempts to provide fonts that cover large amounts of the unicode space - [search for 'Pan-Unicode Fonts'](http://www.google.com/search?q=pan-Unicode%20font) to get an overview.

---

[☕](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) (U+2615 - 'Hot Beverage' ;)

Comment: After poking around for a while, I found Arial Unicode.ttf which pretty much has every major language, cyrillic, arabic, chinese, etc.

Comment: @TomKincaid For "low fidelity" you could use the [UniFoundry's font](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html), which is of low typographic quality but covers over 65000 Unicode codepoints.

Comment: Noteworthy: historical design considerations prevent any font having more than 1 `unsigned short` characters - 65,535 different glyphs. A few code points may share a glyph - Latin Capital `A` and Greek Capital `Alpha`, for example, but that's about all you can do to artifically extend the range.